# Pseudo-IPv4 regex

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose that the maximum IP can contain the maximum number of 999 in each "dot" bracket,i.e. 999.999.999.999 is the largest available.
 I've checked the regex ([0-9]+.){3}[0-9] in the calculator. So, why the program throws the run-time error "parsing "?([0-9]+.){3}[0-9]" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExCs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rawData;
            Regex filter = new Regex(@"?<ip>([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]"); //run-time error 

            rawData=File.ReadAllText("Query list");

            MatchCollection theMatches = filter.Matches(rawData);

            foreach (Match theMatch in theMatches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ip: {0}\n",theMatch.Groups["ip"]);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

[Official help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHARGUMENT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) wasn't so helpful for me.

"Query list" file content:

```
Reply from 212.77.100.101 www.wp.pl time: 21:37
Reply from 111.41.130.55 www.dupa.pl time: 05:33
Reply from 230.77.100.101 www.whatanannoyingbug.com time: 04:12
Reply from 65.77.100.101 www.foooo.org time: 12:55
Reply from 200.77.100.101 www.example.com time: 07:56
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to surround your entire regex with parentheses, change `?<ip>([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]` to the following:

```
(?<ip>([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9])
```

This is necessary because the `?<name>` syntax for creating a named group only works immediately following an opening parentheses, otherwise `?` means "make the previous element optional".  Since there is no previous element before the `?`, you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to ensure it's a REAL (0-255) IP address:

```
(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))
```

Comment: I would only do this if that might be important to read the file correctly, because it is so much longer and harder to read than the simpler version.  YMMV.